# How do I arrange the status bar to always be on top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar

I'm sure this is a quick fix or there is some setting but for some reason I can't find an answer anywhere.

The UIImageView I have on the screen always is arranged above the status bar, even if I send it to the back as shown in the image.

[image]

How can I always keep the status bar on top? I will be sliding images up off the screen through the top edge so I want them to remain under the bar.

Here is some of my code, where I am generating an image and moving it off the top of the screen:

```
    UIImage *towerBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"towerbg.png"];
    UIImageView *towerBGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:towerBG];
    towerBGView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, towerBGView.frame.size.width, towerBGView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:towerBGView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:towerBGView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    towerBGView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -300, towerBGView.frame.size.width, towerBGView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Your image is located at y-position 0. And that's top of the screen. Are you trying to adjust the position in Interface Builder? If yes, just move it down a bit.

Comment: Well in my app I'm going to have the images slide off the screen by going off the top edge. But they slide over the status bar, I was just using the image to kind of demonstrate that

Comment: So you're doing your UI in code and that image from IB above was just for demonstrating purposes? If yes: then please show the code.

Comment: Alright I posted some of my code used to animate the image off the top of the screen

Comment: I don't see why this would be displayed on top of your status bar. What is your status bar? Where/how are you creating it?

Comment: Hmmm okay me either. I just dragged and dropped a UIView onto my storyboard and it generated a view controller for me with the status bar attached (the one in the image above). I am coding in the file connected with that view controller. Does it matter that I am coding for ios7 perhaps?

Comment: Just switched to run it on ios6, and it works like I want it to… Not sure how to fix this for ios7

Comment: Try to get rid of the storyboard. Add the status bar in code. I suspect the IB status bar is created later and will be under your image. But just guessing. Alternatively, embed your controller into a UINavigationController. That will come with a top bar (UINavigationBar). Then you won't have to worry at all.

Comment: @Krumelur Huh? Status bar is rendered by iOS, the storyboard is just a mock preview.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that the image is on top of the status bar, it is **underneath** the status bar, but the status bar is **transparent**, and the image has a **black** background. Black on black = black.

In interface builder, in the **view controller's properties**, uncheck all options under **Extended Edges**. This will make your view not appear under the status bar.